# Unable to install/ use Gedit in kali linux

Tags: linux, vmware, gedit

I'am using Kali Linux by offensive security on VMware with Windows 10 64 bit as host operating system.

I've been trying to use `gedit` but am not able to

```
sudo apt-get install gedit
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gedit
```

Comment: You might need to install Gnome in Kali to use Gedit (Gedit comes with Gnome). I am using Xfce so I use the Xfce editor.

Comment: I'm not familiar with offsensive security provided images, but gedit might simply not be available in your configured apt repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. I suggest you look up how to manage apt repos and also using `apt-cache search` before jumping into Kali specifically.

Answer (score 2):

`gedit` is missing in the standard distribution.

Do the following (using another installed editor):

- Run the command `leafpad /etc/apt/sources.list`
- Ensure the contents of `sources.list` are as follows:

  ```
    deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main contrib non-free 
    deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free 
    deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.0 Kali - Official Snapshot i386 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20130905327-07:57]/ kali contrib main non-free
  ```
- Save the changes : `apt-get update`
- Now you can run : `apt-get install gedit`.

For more information see the article
[Installing gedit on kali linux](https://renouncedthoughts.wordpress.com/2014/01/02/installing-gedit-on-kali-linux/).

Answer (score 0):

Run the command "apt install gedit" after "sudo apt update"

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and a [help]. Do not copy parts from the answer posted by others.

Answer (score 0):

Run sudo apt update
Then Run apt install gedit

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).